# Flutter iOS custom URL scheme

Tags: ios, url, flutter, url-scheme

I'm using [uni_links](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links)  for deep linking in android and custom url scheme for iOS, i can't configure `info.plist` to do what i want, it's mentioned in Readme of the package that i need to paste this in `info.plist`

```
<?xml ...>
<!-- ... other tags -->
<plist>
<dict>
  <!-- ... other tags -->
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
      <string>Editor</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
      <string>[ANY_URL_NAME]</string>
      <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
      <array>
        <string>[YOUR_SCHEME]</string>
      </array>
    </dict>
  </array>
  <!-- ... other tags -->
</dict>
</plist>
```

for example my url is https://myurl.com/vs/match/1111

the last segment in my url is a match id and it changes so how can implement this in info.plist ?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the iOS project's Associated Domains and URL Schemes through the Info.plist editor on Xcode, similar to how it's demonstrated on this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/receive#apple_platforms). Then to match the URL you've provided, the root domain needs to be configured as an Associated Domain for the app to handle it as a Universal Link.

Comment: link is broken.